A word that resonates with 'powerlessness, incompetence, limits, smallness'?
I need a word that will be used by a God to describe humans as 'powerless, incompetent, limited, small' creatures. Though it is not meant to be in a derogatory manner. The God here is simply describing the shortcomings of humans without belittling them. The God loves humans but simply recognizes them for being 'what they are' and so wants to create better creatures.
This is the sentence:

She wanted to create perfect beings who were not bound by the --- of humans. Beings who could reach where humans would have if not for their.

Basically, I need something akin to 'limitations' but with more focus on powerlessness and incapability which come naturally by virtue of being human.

I suggest asthenia.

want of strength, weakness, infirmity
of the body; its native weakness and frailty.


Thanks. While 'astheneia' itself doesn't work, the word 'infirmity' you used in the description works perfectly for my purposes, so I'll go with that.

Cool. Yeah, I did realize this was a bit heavy for the your sentence. I'd initially answered fraility, which is also a good choice.

Isn't it spelled asthenia? And is fraility supposed to be fragility or frailty?

Yeah, asthenia and frailty. Thanks for pointing out.
